# how to call multiple setupIndication using RxAndroidBle

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-java, rx-java2, rxandroidble

I am trying to read the value after firing the `rxBleConnection.setupIndication(UUID)` I have many `characteristics` `UUIDs` and I want to line up using RxJava in a way that I can get consolidated values just the way we get using `Single.Zip` or `Observable.zip`

For example, using `RxAndroidBle` we can read multiple characteristics, would it be possible to do the same for `setupIndication`. As `setupIndication` is returning `Observable<Observable<byte[]>>` it is not possible to zip i guess.

[here is the library that I am using](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle)

**What I expect**

```
Disposable disposable = device.establishConnection(false)
                .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> Observable.zip(
                        rxBleConnection.setupIndication(UUID1),
                        rxBleConnection.setupIndication(UUID2),
                        rxBleConnection.setupIndication(UUID3),
                        rxBleConnection.setupIndication(UUID4),
                        BLEReading::new
                ))
                .subscribe(
                        model -> {
                            // Process your model.

                            Log.e(TAG , "FINAL DATA ");
                        },
                        throwable -> {
                            // Handle an error here.
                        }
                );
```

Currently, I have to perform the `setupIndication` for all 5 charactericts.

```
connectDisposible = device.establishConnection(false)
                .flatMap(rxBleConnection->rxBleConnection.setupIndication(UUID1))
                .flatMap(notificationObservable -> notificationObservable)
                .subscribe(
                        bytes -> {
                            Log.e(TAG,"Notification bytes"+Arrays.toString(BLEUtils.toHex(bytes)));

                        },
                        throwable -> {
                            Log.e(TAG,"Notification Error "+throwable.getMessage());

                        }
                );
```

**Edit**

```
connectDisposible = device.establishConnection(false)
                .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> Observable.zip(
                        rxBleConnection.setupIndication(UUID1).flatMap(it -> it),
                        rxBleConnection.setupIndication(UUID2).flatMap(it -> it),
                        rxBleConnection.setupIndication(UUID3).flatMap(it -> it),
                        rxBleConnection.setupIndication(UUID4).flatMap(it -> it),
                        rxBleConnection.setupIndication(UUID5).flatMap(it -> it),

                        BLEReading::new
                ))
                .subscribe(
                        model -> {
                            //control never reaches here

                            Log.e(TAG , "FINAL DATA "+model);
                        },
                        throwable -> {
                            // Handle an error here.
                            Log.e(TAG , "error"+throwable.getMessage());

                        }
                );
```

however, in logcat i can the indications are successfully set.

```
 setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 705f68f7-83c9-6562-b2c5 enable: true
 setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 314fae3a-d0cf-51c4-4a67 enable: true
 setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 8599c5ba-f827-2d16-ce14 enable: true
 setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 6fbba050-e87b-6ea8-6e5d enable: true
```

Comment: Do you expect the indications to be disabled after the first indication from each characteristic? Or should they be like 1'st indications from characteristic A, B, C, D, E, 2'nd indication from A, B, C, D, E, 3'rd... and so on?

Comment: it is a mix of both. for example, for characteristics A, B, C there will be an only single indication and for D and E  there will be multiple indications to get the new data everytime.

Comment: `Single.zip` and `Observable.zip` emits events when _all_ of the sources will emit. So having an equivalent in your case you would only get a single emission — since A, B, C emit only once.

Comment: Okay, but currently `rxBleConnection.setupIndication(UUID1)` just emitting the `Observable<Observable<byte[]>>` not the `Single<byte[]>` so how could we handle this within `Zip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to have all indications lined up is to flatMap the indication observables into individual indications. Just have in mind that each emission to the subscribe block will happen when *all* of the indication observables will emit.

Using `NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP` to not miss emissions that happen in response to setting Client Characteristic Configuration (CCC) Descriptor.

```
Disposable disposable = device.establishConnection(false)
                .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> Observable.zip(
                        rxBleConnection.setupIndication(UUID1, NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP).flatMap(it -> it),
                        rxBleConnection.setupIndication(UUID2, NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP).flatMap(it -> it),
                        rxBleConnection.setupIndication(UUID3, NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP).flatMap(it -> it),
                        rxBleConnection.setupIndication(UUID4, NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP).flatMap(it -> it),
                        BLEReading::new
                ))
                .subscribe(
                        model -> {
                            // Process your model.

                            Log.e(TAG , "FINAL DATA ");
                        },
                        throwable -> {
                            // Handle an error here.
                        }
                );
```

Comment: I tried your code and it sets the indication but does not return the value and control neither comes to `FINAL DATA` or `throwable`. See my edit please

Comment: This should work as expected given each characteristic emits after it is set to send notification. Add `.doOnNext(bytes -> Log.i("emission", "UUIDX"))` after each `.flatMap(it -> it)` and you will get the individual behaviour of each notification.

Comment: Even i thought the same that it should work but , it is not printing the `UUIDX` in the console and the last thing what I can see it `uuid: 72cd0e39-cd22-415d-5eae-0a71b4861f3e enable: true`

Comment: Ahh `NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP` worked and now i can see the consolidated data. i tried few mode and this one fits well not sure though what it does as the library too big and I could not catchup few things

Comment: There is [Javadoc that tries to explain what is exactly done in each `NotificationSetupMode`](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/1c6a2a932509e016a42d32c51bbaa608507621c9/rxandroidble/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble2/NotificationSetupMode.java#L21)